# Which tags should I consider using for logging a multi-user Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, multi-user

I'm maintaining a Rails 3.2 application. The client wants some errors  fixed. However, some of them are timeout errors, and the application is multi-user, so using default logging makes it difficult to determine which action is causing them. The client doesn't want an external third-party logging system like Rollbar, so improving the existing logging is the only viable approach.

I'd rather use the logger provided by Rails as opposed to a new gem, to ensure that the change to the application is minimised, rather than degrading performance, adding new errors, or requiring additional maintenance.

I'm having difficulty finding good documentation about tagged logging in any version of Rails, let alone Rails 3.2

The Rails Guide [Configuring Rails Applications](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) has some info, but it's not centred around logging.

The Rails Guide "Debugging Rails Applications" mentions the concept of [tagged logging](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#tagged-logging), but no specifics. Justin Weiss' article [Keeping Your Logs From Becoming an Unreadable Mess](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/keeping-your-logs-from-becoming-an-unreadable-mess/) is a nice introduction, but doesn't have enough information. It talks about `config.log_tags` having options based on attributes from [ActionDispatch::Request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) but the documentation for that class is general purpose, and not opinionated enough to suggest which methods to use, and which ones not to use, and why.

Which tags should I consider using for logging a multi-user Rails application, and which ones should I avoid, and why?

Answer (score 3):

Using Rails' `ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging` logger is an excellent choice.

Tags specified in `config.log_tags` are computed by `Rails::Rack::Logger` on every requests.

In addition to `ActionDispatch::Request` attributes, `Proc`s that receive the request can be specified ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e4b0a5f66ebd2b7f29e4f868d2f6b2504df091e6/railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb#L46-L55)). This opens access to the Rack env.

```
config.log_tags [:uuid, proc { |request| ExampleService.call(request.env) }]
```

To access higher level APIs a simple `around_filter` in an `ActionController` will suffice.

```
around_filter :current_user_tag

def current_user_tag
  logger.tagged("CU_#{current_user.id}") do
    yield
  end
end
```

Sample out with the above `around_filter` and `config.log_tags = [:uuid]`

```
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] Started GET "/users" for ::1 at 2016-09-16 16:15:20 +0100
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52]   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered users/_user.html.erb (0.2ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.1ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered layouts/_nav_links_for_auth.html.erb (0.2ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.8ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] [CU_1]   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
[830bb7df-b760-4537-94a7-62ab0f862e52] Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 83.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

In a multi-user app I would recommand the following tags:

- Request ID
- Current User ID (e.g. `CU_1`)
- Current Admin ID (e.g. `AD_8`)

Comment: what is "ExampleService" in this context? Rails model?

Comment: `ExampleService` is a class responsible to compute tags. This is recommended when the logic becomes complex.